# Unable to connect to WPA2 Personal

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom, wpa2

Today I've installed a new Asus RT-N10E router, as I switched from DSL to a cable ISP. Honestly, I can't recall which security settings I used on the previous one. Thing is, that's I want it to be WPA2 Personal (with AES, that an only option in my router); WPA-TKIP works at about 50 Mb/s but I want the better 60 Mb/s throughput and security of WPA2-AES. Windows XP and both phones connect to the WLAN correctly. My Ubuntu 13.10 with Broadcom STA driver (BCM4313) also connects to the network, at least the indicator says so, but I can't access the internet w/ WPA2-AES.

I put the results of the wireless-info script on pastebin.com because of the question length limitation. So, here it is: http://pastebin.com/2xJ6MYit

Comment: Visit http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082305&p=12350385#post12350385 and then reply there with the result of the script mentioned in the link. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2131289,  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175219 and  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174901&p=12791184 have useful info.

Comment: Also, are you using wicd https://launchpad.net/wicd http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicd in lieu of network-manager https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager ? Broadcom users seem to have much better luck with that and with the (admittedly proprietary) broadcom-wl driver, rather than the brcmsmac driver.

Comment: Somebody has deleteted his responses, so it looks like it's my monologue. :/ Sorry to ask like that, but is there an easy way? e.g. install new driver. I'm pretty new to Linux.

Comment: I deleted my questions after you answered them and incorporated your answers into the original question. When you have the data from the result of the script I mentioned, then please add that into the question as well, so when someone else comes to look at this, then they don't have to chew through the comments to see the whole picture. That's what Braiam is trying to get at with his comment, that we want questioners to improve their questions when they dial back with more info.

Comment: I've added the output from that script.